# Shared state between WebSocketHandler and RequestHandler

Tags: websocket, tornado

I am writing chat app and I need session data in my websocket handler. Problem is that login and logout is done by AJAX request, and updating/clearing cookie cannot be seen by websocket handler - it sees only state from the time website was initially rendered. But it cannot see, when cookie is changed by AJAX request. Do you have any idea, how this can be implemented?

```
import json

import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

class BaseHandler(object):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db

    def get_current_user(self):
        id = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
        user = self.db.get_user_by_id(id) if id else ''
        return user

class JsonHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, response):
        if response:
            response = json.dumps(response)
        TemplateHandler.write(self, response)

    @property
    def body(self):
        return json.loads(self.request.body.decode())

class WebSocketHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    pass

class Login(JsonHandler):
    def post(self):
        login = self.body.get('login')
        password = self.body.get('password')
        user = self.db.validate_user(login, password)
        if user:
            self.set_secure_cookie('user', str(user['id']))
            self.write(user)
        else:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(401)

class Logout(JsonHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.clear_cookie('user')
        self.write('')


class WebSocket(WebSocketHandler):
    clients = set()

    def open(self):
        WebSocket.clients.add(self)

    def on_close(self):
        WebSocket.clients.remove(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        # how to use method self.get_current_user()
        # it uses self.get_secure_cookie('user')
        # but it is not updated dynamically by Login and Logout handlers
        # because websocket does not share state with them

        for client in WebSocket.clients:
            client.write_message(message)
```

Comment: Ok, I have actually found the solution. Problem was that websocket sees cookie state only from the time websocket was initialized. Solution? Keep cookie both for authenticated and anonymous users with session ID. Session ID will be kept in database, together with corresponding logged in user ID. And speaking about shared state between websocket and request handlers, you can always use singleton application instance with dictionary with keys equal to session ID. I hope that will help anyone who encounter similar problem.

Comment: great you found a solution yourself! maybe you can share your new code with us.

Comment: Sure :) I haven't written it yet, but  I am sure it will work. I will share it with you within couple of days, after implementing new session design :)